# How do I make a List of Lists?

Tags: c#, list, json.net

Part of my class file

```
namespace Calendar
{
    class CalendarModel
    {
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string name { get; set; }
```

In my implementation file, I declared a private variable

```
private List<CalendarModel> people;
```

In a method, I am getting my JSON Object with this code

```
people = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CalendarModel>>((string)fileContainingJSONObject);
```

How would I create an Array of people? Then how would I access its members (later)?

Comment: Declare a `List<List<CalendarModel>>` and add `people` to that list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just declare a list of list of CalendarModel

```
var crowd = new private List<List<CalendarModel>>();
```

...

```
people = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CalendarModel>>((string)fileContainingJSONObject);
crowd.add(people)
```

To access the properties of the `CalendarModel` objects:

```
crowd[peopleIndex][calendarModelIndex].name
```

Comment: Of course, you'll want to initialize `crowd` somewhere first.

Comment: how would I access the member properties like name?

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm a little confused how I'd access the member property. If I want to update it for a people.name = "Steve Jobs". How would I find the right peopleIndex? Do I use a foreach loop the. Use a secondary loop to look at the calendarModelIndex?